# How to disable a button after a certain date [JAVA]

Tags: java, button

I was wondering how I could disable a button after a date like July 4, 2015?
I have found an example on this site of how to disable a button on that date but not the subsequent days after that date.

FROM Example:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
if (month == Calendar.JUNE && dayOfMonth == 29 && year == 2014) {
  // June 29, 2014
  myButton.setEnabled(true);
}
else
{
  // NOT June 29, 2014
  myButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ways that you can check your conditions :

Get an instance of the `Calendar` and set your prescribed date.

```
int dayOfMonth = 29;
int month = Calendar.JUNE;
int year = 2014;

Calendar disableDate = Calendar.getInstance();
disableDate.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
```

Then: using the before/after/equals

```
 //enable the button for dates after your prescribed date
 if(today.after(disableDate))

 //enable the button for dates before your prescribed date
 if(today.before(disableDate))

 //enable the button only on your prescribed date
 if(today.equals(disableDate))
```

Note: You may have to strip off / zero time from the date instances if you are going to do any of these as the time will be taken into account.

To check for date equality:

```
public static boolean calendarCheck(Calendar calendar1, Calendar calendar2)
{
  return zeroCalendar(calendar1).compareTo(zeroCalendar(calendar2)) == 0;
}
```

To zero Time

```
public static Calendar zeroCalendar(Calendar calendar)
{
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);    
   calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
   return calendar;
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This Answer ignores the issue of time zone in determining the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java. Instead use either Joda-Time or the new java.time package in Java 8 or later (inspired by Joda-Time).

## Time Zone

Time zone is critical in determining the date. For example a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal where it is still 'yesterday'.

## Joda-Time

```
LocalDate dueDate = new LocalDate( 2015 , DateTimeConstants.JULY , 4 ) ;
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montréal" ) ;
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now( zone ) ;
Boolean disableButton = now.isAfter( dueDate ) ;
```